# Android: RelativeLayout + FrameLayout -> View align issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to align the top `View` which is wrapped inside `FrameLayout` to the top of the `ImageView` which has top `padding/margin`. The issue is that this view is aligning above the padding/margin of `ImageView`. Is there any way how to ignore margins and padding's of `ImageView` and align that view to top of visible image?

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/stop_timeline_icon"
android:layout_above="@id/stop_timeline_icon"
```

parameters are just pushing bottom edge of that `FrameLayout` above parent. (so I cant see it at all)

This is what I want to achieve. Orange line is my `FrameLayout`, grey square is my icon with top margin:

[image]

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/clickArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_selector_background">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/stop_timeline_top_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/stop_timeline_icon"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/stop_timeline_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/stop_timeline_icon"
            android:layout_above="@id/stop_timeline_icon">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/stop_timeline_top"
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/doveGrey" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stop_timeline_icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/stop_icon"
            app:tint="@color/doveGrey"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using margin in minus dp,Like this,

```
android:layout_marginStart="-16dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a negative margin to the `FrameLayout` in the opposite direction of that of the `ImageView`.

As the ImageView margin is `android:layout_marginTop`, then add `android:layout_marginBottom`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/stop_timeline_top_layout"
    ...
    android:layout_marginBottom="-18dp"
```